# How to pass parameters to child router in Angular 2 for deep linking?

Tags: typescript, routes, angular, deep-linking

Basically, if I have one component that signals a child routing component, like:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/users/...', //CHILD ROUTING COMPONENT
        name: 'Users',
        component: UsersComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    }
])
export class App {
   constructor(private _router: Router) {}
   ucFirst(str:string){
        var parts = str.split(' ');
         for(var i = 0, ilen = parts.length; i < ilen; i++){
            parts[i] = parts[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + parts[i].slice(1);
         }
         return parts.join(' ');
     }
   ngOnInit() {
     //Handle deep links if exist
     var baseHref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
        var path = location.href.replace(baseHref, '');

         if(path.length){
             let slugs = path.split('/');
             for(let i = 0, ilen = slugs.length; i < ilen; i++){
                slugs[i] = this.ucFirst(slugs[i]);
             }
             this._router.navigate(slugs);
         }
     }
 }
```

And then the child router uses some kind of parameter in one of the paths, like:

```
@RouteConfig([{
    path: '/',
    name: 'UserList',
    component: UserListComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
},{
    path: '/:id', 
    name: 'UserView', 
    component: UserViewComponent
}])
```

How do I make deep links work?  I can use the code to get to the grandchild view, but deep links fail (Error No route 'users/1' where 1 is the :id).  Basically I need to handle half of the path in the parent router and half in the child router but I have not found the way to do so.  I can make deep links work as long as they exist completely in the parent but I am working on a larger project and want to make the set up more modular.

I have put my code in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/7cKBEwQmFSJrDFWhL4EV?p=preview
It works locally (minus the deep links) but not on plunker, which I've never used before so I imagine this is kind of simple configuration issue on my part.  But it at least gives you an idea of the attempt at modularization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to navigate using `url`,

and to do it correctly you need to use [navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html) instead of `navigate`, like this

```
 this._router.navigateByUrl(path);
```

Comment: Actually in this example, should be `this._router.navigateByUrl(path)` , but navigateByUrl seems to work great!  Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the correction, I assumed that you are generating a `url` of some sort in that `for loop`, my bad....     You're welcome!